# splite date with Ice_Cube in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ice-cube

I want to create an Api that it get start_time and end_time and the number of month that should split start time and end time and return a collection that i can loop through that and save the data in to the database.
for example every week from 14:05 to 18:30 on Sundays.
this is what everything that i did:

def create_recurring_schedules
      number=0
      if recurring
        schedule = Schedule.new(start_time, end_time: end_time)

```
    schedule.add_recurrence_rule Rule.weekly

     if month == 12

        dates = schedule.occurrences_between(start_time,  start_time + 1.year) 
     elsif month == 3
        logger.info "################### The 3 month is #{self.s_month} #############################################"
        dates = schedule.occurrences_between(start_time, start_time + 3.month)
     elsif month == 6
        logger.info "################### The 6 month is #{month} ###########################################"
        dates = schedule.occurrences_between(start_time, start_time + 6.month)
     elsif month == 1

     dates = schedule.occurrences_between(start_time , start_time + 1.months)
   end
    dates.each do |date|
      number +=1
      logger.info "################### Start number #{number} #############################################"
      ClinicSchedule.create(user_id: user_id, clinic_id: clinic_id, month: month,
                                  start_time: date.start_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
                                  end_time: date.end_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
                                  date: date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), recurring: true,
                                  recurrence_id: recurrence_id)
      logger.info "################### Recurrence ID: "
      logger.info recurrence_id
      logger.info "################### End Recurrence ID ###########################################################"
    end
  end
end
```

the problem that i faced with that is on this case:

```
dates = schedule.occurrences_between(start_time , start_time + 1.months)
```

when i set start_time from four month later for example 2017-10-13 16:20. it only give 35 weeks and don't give 53 week that start from four month later.

Comment: Why are you doing `Time.now+start_time`?

Comment: it is one of the craziest thing that i did, the start_time can be two month later. when i used Time.now stand alone it work well and i did this to see what happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem arises from `s_time=(Time.now+start_time).to_i`. It seems that `start_time` is an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. You are trying to add `Time` and `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` that is probably not the thing you want to achieve.

`schedule.occurrences_between` at least expects two instances of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. Therefore, you could do something like this:

```
s_time = Time.zone.now
e_time = s_time + 1.month

schedule.occurrences_between(s_time, e_time)
```

UPD: Actually, you do not need that long conditional with months:

```
schedule.occurrences_between(start_time, start_time + month.months)
```

And instead of defining and incrementing `number` use [`#each_with_index`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index)

Comment: i did that but i don't know why when i set start_time + 1.month i get 44 week. i supposed to be 4 week not 44 weeks

Comment: What do you mean by "i get 44 week"?

Comment: I mean about the above loop, dates.each do |date| ==> it's loop 44 times and i save 44

Comment: What if instead of `schedule.rrule Rule.weekly` you will use `schedule.add_recurrence_rule Rule.weekly`?

Comment: i get same result